# Azure Deployment Slots with multiple websites hosted under one App Service plan

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-plans, azure-deployment-slots

I am in the process of moving multiple websites to Azure under one Premium App Service plan. Following the instructions provided here https://dotnetthoughts.net/deploying-multiple-application-in-webapp/ I was able to host multiple sites under one App Service Plan but I am struggling to figure out how I can make use of Deployment Slots for multiple sites. It looks like there is only one "Production" Slot per App Service plan which means I can only swap a Deployment Slot with the only Production Slot. Does someone know how each website can have a Production Slot and a corresponding "Testing" Slot?

Comment: It's a bad idea to repurpose "slots" to get multiple apps, when azure app service specifically allows you to add multiple apps to a single app service plan for the same price (as they share the same CPU, memory). Hierarchy is app service plan => apps => app slots.

Answer (score 3):

Each App Service plan tier supports a different number of deployment slots. Azure App Service Plan Premium (v2) supports = 20 and standard supports = 5 deployment slots.

Based on your requirement you can put all your apps in one App Service plan and have multiple deployment slots. If you have multiple deployment slots for an app, all deployment slots also run on the same VM instances.
Since you pay for the computing resources your App Service plan allocates, you can potentially save money by putting multiple apps into one App Service plan. You can continue to add apps to an existing plan as long as the plan has enough resources to handle the load. However, note that the apps in the same App Service plan all share the same compute resources. Overloading an App Service plan can potentially cause downtime for your new and existing apps.

You don't get charged for using the App Service features that are available to you (configuring custom domains, SSL certificates, deployment slots, backups, etc.)
Checkout this document for more details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-staging-slots

Answer (score 3):

You can have multiple web apps under a single Azure App Service Plan. Meanwhile, under every web app(App Service), you can create multiple slots and you can have production and staging for every web app separately.

Comment: Except for the free plan as of March 2020. It is called "F1" and it has no slot support.